# Cannot find module node js

Tags: node.js

Facing issue while executing [image]query.js

Comment: Please install stream-buffers. link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-buffers

Comment: Instead of the image, place the text.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The error says: "Cannot find module 'stream-buffers'".

You should install it using:

`npm install stream-buffers --save`